# Returned AJAX string to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, string

This is what I have. I have an AJAX call that returns a string (data.d) like this:

```
{"id": "03100500", "name": "Book I"},{"id": "03100507", "name": "Book I - ALT"},{"id": "03100505", "name": "Book I - M"},{"id": "03100600", "name": "Book II"}
```

I've tried:

```
var books = JSON.parse(data.d);
```

Basically getting an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON"

End result i'd like:

```
var newArray = [{"id": "03100500", "name": "Book I"},{"id": "03100507", "name": "Book I - ALT"},{"id": "03100505", "name": "Book I - M"},{"id": "03100600", "name": "Book II"}]
```

Not even sure if it's possible

Comment: Does your string really have a closing `]` and no opening `[`?

Comment: opps. I'll fix it

Comment: Where are you getting data.d from? Is it `jQuery.ajax()`? If so and you are supplying a dataType of `json` jQuery will already have parsed your response for you. ["json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). You should edit your question and include the source of `data.d`

Comment: Is it possible that there's an unescaped `"` somewhere in one of the names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the array delimiters, the string isn't valid JSON. Given the string without array delimiters, you can just add them before parsing:

```js
let s = `{"id": "03100500", "name": "Book I"},{"id": "03100507", "name": "Book I - ALT"},{"id": "03100505", "name": "Book I - M"},{"id": "03100600", "name": "Book II"}`

// make new string with `[]` delimiters:
let o = JSON.parse('[' + s + ']')
console.log(o)
```

If the value is going to be flawed in more complicated ways like undelimited nested arrays, it will be harder and probably worth fixing it on the server if possible.

Comment: I thought that too.. But now just get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position"

Comment: @54696d are you getting that error in the above snippet where I used your string? If not, you need to post the **actual** string in the question, otherwise you are making us guess.

Comment: This seems like a solution to an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Recommending blindly wrapping a resulting string with braces does not seem like a good idea

Comment: @Marie, I'm not *blindly* wrapping anything. The expected result is an array. The reason the string is not parsing to that array is that it's missing the outer delimiters.

Comment: Thanks @MarkMeyer It was an extra comma at the end of that string messing everything up.

Comment: Nice @54696d, glad it was an easy fix.

Comment: @MarkMeyer It is a workaround for another issue. It should, at the very least, be labeled as such. And work arounds are never ideal.

Comment: @Marie, you're swinging at windmills here. This answers the question as posed. The last paragraph suggesting fixing it on the server covers other cases.

Comment: IMO the goal of StackOverflow is to provide the most correct answer. So the primary answer should be "You are recieving malformed JSON which should be fixed." and as a secondary you can provide a temporary workaround if that is not possible but it should be clear that it is a workaround and not optimal

Answer (score 0):

I think the missing [ was a copy and paste mistake. Assuming that, you are probably calling JSON.parse on an object. See image below:

[image]

Comment: "on already valid json" does not make any sense. I think you are saying they are calling JSON.parse on a javascript object?

Comment: What he posted there is valid json not a string. Sometimes someone may try and call JSON.parse on an object aka "already valid json" which will throw that error in the image I posted. I will update the verbiage to be clear.

Comment: JSON is a string. not an object. if it is an object it is not JSON. JSON stands for Javascript Object *NOTATION*

Comment: I think because .json files are object and array literals and primitives that some devs, including my self, sometimes loosely use 'json' to refer to json like data. I work with tons of json files everyday and am certainly guilty of calling the content of .json files json. That being said, my answer there is valid despite the technical hiccup. It is an example of what will happen if you call JSON.parse on an object and then use it properly on a string of json. Cheers.

Comment: The contents of a JSON file are JSON. After being parsed or when hard coded in a javascript file it is just a javascript object, not JSON or a JSON object. Mistakes happen but it is not correct and when teaching newbies you should be mindful to not spread misinformation.